# Find, with proof, the set of all points where $h$ is continuous, where $h(x)$ is the Dirichlet function

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $h:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be defined by $$h(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> x& \text{if}\quad x \in \mathbb Q\\
> 0 &\text{if}\quad x \notin \Bbb Q.
> \end{cases}$$
>   Find the set of points where $h$ is continuous.

So let $x=0$. let $x_n$ be a seqeunce of irrational numbers. since $h(x_n)=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ we have $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} h(x_n)=0$. While $h(x)=0$ since $h(x_n)=h(x)$ then $h$ is continous at $0$ or $x$.

Is this the way to prove this?

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question into a more readable format.

Comment: You are right that $h$ is continuous at $0$. However, you still have to show that $h$ is **not** continuous for every $x \neq 0$.

Comment: Hint: Every open interval shall contain at least one rational and irrational point (use Archimedian property to show this).

Comment: “$h$ is continuous at $0$ or $x$.”  That doesn’t make sense, because you are looking for the values of x where h is continuous, correct?

Comment: the proof for continuity at $0$ is not correct / complete. You have shown that $h$ is continuous at $0$ on $\mathbb Q^c \cup \{ 0 \}$. For a correct proof, take a sequence in $\mathbb R$ and split it into subsequences in $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q^c$.